# How to add timestamps in a Pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a Pandas Series object with a timestamp field `start`:

```
a = pd.Series(index=['preceding_id', 'file', 'start'],  dtype=[np.int, np.str, np.datetime64], )
```

it fails with a

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?
I've been looking for dates and datetime objects in pandas, but the documentation only says how to use it as index - which is not what I want...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Series can only have one data type. If you want to store multiple types in one Series, the Series' type will be `object`, the generic Python type.

```
In [12]: Series([1, 'some string', pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01')])
Out[12]: 
0                      1
1            some string
2    2014-01-01 00:00:00
dtype: object
```

This is no problem. The types of the constituent elements are retained. For example, the Timestamp in the Series above is still a Timestamp, as we can see by accessing it.

```
In [13]: Series([1, 'some string', pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01')])[2]
Out[13]: Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

So, in conclusion, don't specify the datatypes. In general, they'll be handled properly without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want a dataframe?

If so, it would look something like:

```
data = {'preceeding_id': [list of ids],
        'file': [list of files], 
        'start': [list of timestamps]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.start = pd.to_datetime(df.start)
```

Or, if you are reading the data in from a file or something, you could easily use `parse_dates=True` for most of pandas' I/O functions. Pandas is actually pretty fantastic at assigning the correct dtype inherently.

Comment: Yes - eventually I want a DataFrame. I thought about having something like a spreadsheet/DataFrame and adding a row/Series on a given event subsequently. Since I didn't manage to get a single row working, I didn't try the DataFrame.